# Summing up DenseVectors after a groupByKey() works in Pyspark Shell but not in a Spark-Submit

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

So here's some example code of what I'm trying to do:

**First, I'm building sentence feature vectors using Word2Vec:**

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import Word2Vec

# Input data: Each row is a bag of words from a sentence or document.
documentDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
    ("Hi I heard about Spark".split(" "), ),
    ("I wish Java could use case classes".split(" "), ),
    ("Logistic regression models are neat".split(" "), )
], ["text"])
# Learn a mapping from words to Vectors.
word2Vec = Word2Vec(vectorSize=3, minCount=0, inputCol="text", outputCol="result")
model = word2Vec.fit(documentDF)
result = model.transform(documentDF)

Converting output result to an RDD:
result_rdd=result.select("result").rdd
rdd_with_sample_ids_attached = result_rdd.map(lambda x: (1, x[0]))
rdd_with_sample_ids_attached.collect()
```

***output:*** 
[(1, DenseVector([0.0472, -0.0078, 0.0377])), (1, DenseVector([-0.0253, -0.0171, 0.0664])), (1, DenseVector([0.0101, 0.0324, 0.0158]))]

**Now, I do a groupByKey() and find the sum of the DenseVectors in each group as follows:**

```
rdd_sum = rdd_with_sample_ids_attached.groupByKey().map(lambda x: (x[0], sum(x[1])))
rdd_sum.collect()
```

***output:*** 
[(1, DenseVector([0.0319, 0.0075, 0.1198]))]

As shown, this code works perfectly in the pyspark shell. However, when I submit the same code as a spark-submit, I get the following error:

```
File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1465567204576_0170/container_1465567204576_0170_01_000002/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/functions.py", line 39, in _
   jc = getattr(sc._jvm.functions, name)(col._jc if isinstance(col, Column) else col)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jvm'
```

I have tried repartitioning the RDD to a single partition, same error.
Any help, please?

Comment: The error suggests that `sc` is `NoneType`. Maybe you're dealing with a large dataset and your cluster is dead? This is very possible esp. you're using `groupByKey` which requires the memory large enough to hold any key and its values.

Comment: Also the lambda function after `groupByKey` doesn't give the sum

Comment: Hey! No, I tried with the same sample data set I posted above. Same error. Works in the pyspark shell, doesn't work when I spark-submit the same code in a .py file. Also, the lambda function does do a sum - it was a typo in the question. I have edited my code in the question.

I'm able to unfurl the list of DenseVectors associated with the grouped ID, and also do a len() operation. Its just the sum() that fails. Frustratingly, it works in the pyspark shell and ipython notebook, so I feel I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out!
The problem was that I had an import function in my script as follows:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
```

This imported the sum() function which replaced the in-built pythonic sum(). When I removed this import function, it worked correctly. When the pythonic inbuilt sum() function is capable of adding DenseVectors, the imported sum() from pyspark.sql.functions cannot do so.

Comment: Apparently this is not in your question :)